# Dropping tables from mysql database after uninstalling the app

Tags: mysql, django

I have installed the [django-notification-system](https://pypi.org/project/django-notification-system/) and again uninstalled this package from my django application then made makeimigration and migrate to put its tables on mysql database.

However after **installing**, In the project database list I see tables `notification_system_notification`, `notification_system_target_user_record`, and `notification_system_target` , and after **uninstalling** the package, still these tables remain in the tables' lists. Is there any way to get rid of them without manually dropping/deleting them?

Comment: migrate app to zero before deleting it

Comment: You mean manually deleting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should migrate your app to zero prior to removing app from `INSTALLED_APPS` which would effectively remove that app tables from database

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/)

> If you want to reverse all migrations applied for an app, use the name
> zero:
>
> `python manage.py migrate books zero`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I followed your solution, however still see the trace of previews tables even tho I migrated the app to zero before deleting it. Can I drop them manually after migrating to zero and removing it from `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: What exactly did you run as this package has only 3 tables which would definitely be deleted when zeroing migrations

Answer (score 0):

Once an install/uninstall script has already run, the only way to clear these tables would be to drop them manually or through a script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I am a bit scared if I change my mind and want to reinstall this app again face with missing tables errors! Isn't it?

Comment: As long as you are sure that these are the tables related to your installation, with next install, these tables will be reinstalled. These tables were installed automatically right?

Comment: This is not good idea as package will be left as already migrated in migrations table